# Aligning preferences of a set of equations

Tags: math-mode, equations, alignat

In the following example:

(i) I was wondering how to correctly align the first calligraphic letter `\mathcal{S}` of the second line with the first calligraphic letter `\mathcal{C}` of the third line. It doesn't seem right using `\hphantom{+}`.

(ii) Besides, I would like to have the equation numbers centered in the middle, i.e., roughly somewhere between lines 2 & 3 for the first equation, and somewhere between lines 6 & 7 for the second equation, without splitting the equations into two math environments, as this would create an undesired vertical space between them.

Thanks.

---

**EDIT**

In light of @barbarabeeton comment below, part (i) of the question is solved using `{}+{}`.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}    
    \begin{alignat}{2}
    f_x &= &&+\frac12 \big\{ \mathcal{S}(\theta,a_{\theta})a_1 - \mathcal{S}(\theta,a_{\theta})a_2 +\mathcal{C}(\theta,a_{\theta})a_3 - \mathcal{C}(\theta,a_{\theta})a_4 \nonumber \\
    &&&{}+{}\mathcal{S}(\theta,a_{\theta})(a_2-a_1) - \sin(\theta+a_{\theta})(a_2-a_1) \nonumber \\
    &&&-\mathcal{C}(\theta,a_{\theta})(a_3-a_4)+ \cos(\theta+a_{\theta})(a_3-a_4) \nonumber \\
    &&&-\mathcal{C}(\theta,a_{\theta})(b_2-b_1)a_{\theta} - \mathcal{S}(\theta,a_{\theta})(b_3-b_4)a_{\theta} \big\}, \label{eq:ax} \\
    f_y &= &&-\frac12 \big\{ \mathcal{C}(\theta,a_{\theta})a_1 + \mathcal{C}(\theta,a_{\theta})a_2 +\mathcal{S}(\theta,a_{\theta})a_3 - \mathcal{S}(\theta,a_{\theta})a_4 \nonumber \\
    &&&-\mathcal{C}(\theta,a_{\theta})(a_2-a_1) + \cos(\theta+a_{\theta})(a_2-a_1) \nonumber \\
    &&&- \mathcal{S}(\theta,a_{\theta})(a_3-a_4) + \sin(\theta+a_{\theta})(a_3-a_4) \nonumber \\
    &&&-\mathcal{S}(\theta,a_{\theta})(b_2-b_1)a_{\theta} - \mathcal{C}(\theta,a_{\theta})(b_3-b_4)a_{\theta} \big\}. \label{eq:ay} 
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `align` should work as well as `alignat`.  And `\hphantom{{}+{}}` is quite a reasonable way to shove the `\mathcal{S}` to the desired location.  The matter of how to position the equation numbers is more complicated, and needs thinking because of the very wide "first" lines.

Comment: Thank you, @barbarabeeton. Do you have an explanation for using `{}+{}`, which actually does the job?

Comment: Placing just `+` in braces changes its spacing to "ord".  It needs something on either side to keep the "bin" spacing.  Hence the empty braces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the alignment points and use `split`. I suggest to split the first lines into two and to add some vertical space between the two parts.

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\cS}{\mathcal{S}}
\newcommand{\cC}{\mathcal{C}}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
f_x = +\frac{1}{2} \bigl\{
      & \cS(\theta,a_{\theta})a_1 - \cS(\theta,a_{\theta})a_2 \\
{}+{} &  \cC(\theta,a_{\theta})a_3 - \cC(\theta,a_{\theta})a_4 \\
{}+{} & \cS(\theta,a_{\theta})(a_2-a_1) - \sin(\theta+a_{\theta})(a_2-a_1) \\
{}-{} & \cC(\theta,a_{\theta})(a_3-a_4)+ \cos(\theta+a_{\theta})(a_3-a_4) \\
{}-{} & \cC(\theta,a_{\theta})(b_2-b_1)a_{\theta} - \cS(\theta,a_{\theta})(b_3-b_4)a_{\theta}
\bigr\},
\end{split}\label{eq:ax}
\\[1ex]
\begin{split}
f_y = -\frac{1}{2} \bigl\{
      & \cC(\theta,a_{\theta})a_1 + \cC(\theta,a_{\theta})a_2 \\
{}+{} & \cS(\theta,a_{\theta})a_3 - \cS(\theta,a_{\theta})a_4 \\
{}-{} & \cC(\theta,a_{\theta})(a_2-a_1) + \cos(\theta+a_{\theta})(a_2-a_1) \\
{}-{} & \cS(\theta,a_{\theta})(a_3-a_4) + \sin(\theta+a_{\theta})(a_3-a_4) \\
{}-{} &\cS(\theta,a_{\theta})(b_2-b_1)a_{\theta} - \cC(\theta,a_{\theta})(b_3-b_4)a_{\theta}
\bigr\}.
\end{split}\label{eq:ay} 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Avoid such things as `\frac12`: it's ambiguous and may lead to bad habits.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As I mentioned in the question, part (ii), I'm looking to place the equation numbers in the middle (vertically) of each equation.

Comment: @AEW Simpler approach, then. See edited answer.

Comment: This simpler approach is OK. Nonetheless, I was wondering how to solve a general problem when more than one alignment is needed, i.e., using `alignat` or similar environments.